# How to display the content of a CVS version

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I have selected several projects in my eclipse CVS repository and I have marked them with a new version/tag. 
I would now like to display the content of this new version instead of analysing projects by projects the history of each. 
Is there a solution ?

I've googled and no result for my need (may be wrong key words ?)

Thanks you.

Patrice

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have 1 CVS repository which contains N Eclipse projects.

Create a simple Eclipse project at the root of your CVS repository. That will allow you to import everything as a single project. From this project, you can see the whole history over everything.

When you want to work on a child project, import it from the local disk instead of from the CVS server. Don't forget to disable "Copy files" when you import. Eclipse will notice that these two projects are related (i.e. one is inside of the path of another). Doing CVS operations will now work on the parent project.

That said, you should really consider to [move to a DVCS](http://hginit.com/) :-)

Comment: The current architecture can not be so easily changed as numerous persons already work on this project. If there is not a functionnality to see the content of a CVS version, can you confirm it and I will analyse project one by one. 
Moreover, thanks you :)

Comment: You will have to decide which is more important to you. Either you disturb everyone or you can't get the whole history inside of Eclipse.

Comment: Note that you can use the command line version of CVS to get what you want.